# How to generate a list of which Features are enabled in which Spaces?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm running a Drupal 6.x site with Organic Groups, Features, and Spaces, and I'm interested in generating a list of which Spaces have which Features enabled.  Preferably a table, with Spaces along the Y axis, and Features along the X axis.

Any ideas regarding how to generate this?  I can generate a list of Group Spaces using Views, but can't find a field for the enabled Features.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but the following SQL query provides a list of Group Spaces in which a particular feature (in this case, `atrium_casetracker`) is enabled:

```
 SELECT node.title FROM `spaces_overrides`
 JOIN node ON node.nid=id
 WHERE `object_id` LIKE 'spaces_features'
 AND `value` LIKE '%atrium_casetracker";s:1:"1%'
 ORDER BY title
```